# shopify api: calculate total shipping price

Tags: shopify

There is a nice helper - `shipping_price` - available in liquid templates (for order). Returns total order shipping price (hopefully). How do I get the same via API?

Should I go through order `order.shipping_lines` and sum their `price`? Is that the right way to do it?

**EDIT**

Or, perhaps, `order.subtotal_price` + `order.total_tax`?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the shipping price then summing the shipping line prices is the correct approach.

At this time, there's only ever one shipping line per order but it's built as an array to accomodate potential changes to this situation.